# In Liferay how to share the content from development to test environment?

Tags: deployment, liferay

getting this warning using export and import, how to resolve this ?

[Liferay file size exceeds warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVKjx.png)

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask] and [help/on-topic]: This doesn't look like a programming-related question and you might get better help within the Liferay community (https://liferay.dev/).

Comment: if you can share some information related to this, then it can be highly appreciate

Comment: I'll happily share information on a site where this question is on topic - and I've given a hint where that is above.

Answer (score 0):

"no lorger than 100MB"

You have to enlarge upload file limit in the server configuration.

Comment: Can you please share me the steps to enlarge the file upload limit in liferay portal

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/UipofIB.png